# State pulled from redux store not rendering

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I'm building a simple blog app using React-Redux (with Redux toolkit)

The user enter blog information via a form, where the user id is passed (with the other blog information). This user id is later used to match with the user's name, which is then rendered in a blog post - the problem is that instead of a name, I'm getting `undefined`.

The data flow is like this-

User information is held in a slice as follows:

**usersSlice.js**

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = [
    {id:0, name: 'Dude Lebowski'},
    {id:1, name: 'User 2'},
    {id:2, name: 'User 3'}
]

const usersSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'users',
    initialState,
    reducers: {}
})

export const selectAllUsers = (state) => state.users

export default usersSlice.reducer
```

The user state is extracted into the blog post component, ** AddPostForm**, where is it mapped over and rendered. When a user is selected via the menu, the associated user id is saved to staet as `userId`:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { ADD_POST } from "./postSlice";
import { selectAllUsers } from "../users/usersSlice";

const AddPostForm = () => {

    const [title, setTitle] = useState('')
    const [content, setContent] = useState('')
    const [userId, setUserId] = useState('')
    
    const users = useSelector(selectAllUsers)

    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const onAuthorChanged = e => setUserId(e.target.value)

    const onSavePostClicked = () => {
      if (title && content) {
        dispatch(ADD_POST(title, content,userId));
        setTitle("");
        setContent("");
      }
    };

    
    const usersOptions = users.map(user => (
        <option key = {user.id} value = {user.id}>
            {user.name}
        </option>
    ))


    const canSave = Boolean(title) && Boolean(content) && Boolean(userId)
    

    return (
        <section>
            <h2>Add a New Post</h2>
            <form>
                <label htmlFor="postTitle">Post Title:</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    id="postTitle"
                    name="postTitle"
                    value={title}
                    onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
                />
                <label htmlFor="postAuthor">Author:</label>
                <select id="postAuthor" value={userId} onChange={onAuthorChanged}>
                    <option value=""></option>
                    {usersOptions}
                </select>
                <label htmlFor="postContent">Content:</label>
                <textarea
                    id="postContent"
                    name="postContent"
                    value={content}
                    onChange={(e) => setContent(e.target.value)}
                />
                <button
                    type="button"
                    onClick={onSavePostClicked}
                    disabled = {!canSave}
                >Save Post</button>
            </form>
        </section>
    )
}
export default AddPostForm
```

The posts are mapped over in **PostList.js**, where the user Id is passed as props to the **PostList** component:

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { selectAllPosts } from "./postSlice";
import PostAuthor from "./PostAuthor";

const PostsList = () => {
  const posts = useSelector(selectAllPosts);

  const renderedPosts = posts.map((post) => (
    <article key={post.id}>
      <h3>{post.title}</h3>
      <p>{post.content.substring(0, 100)}</p>
      <p className="postCredit">
        <PostAuthor userId = {post.userId}/>
      </p>
    </article>
  ));

  return (
    <section>
      <h2>Posts</h2>
      {renderedPosts}
    </section>
  );
};
 
export default PostsList;
```

**PostAuthor.js**

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { selectAllUsers } from "../users/usersSlice";

const PostAuthor = ({ userId }) => {
    const users = useSelector(selectAllUsers)

    const author = users.find(user => user.id === userId);

    return <span>by {author ? author.name : 'Unknown author'}</span>
}
export default PostAuthor
```

**postSlice.js**

```
import { createSlice, nanoid } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";


const initialState = [
    {id: '1', title: 'Learning redux toolkit', content:'Meow meow, i tell my human fall asleep on the washing machine, chase ball of string meow in empty rooms, but is good you understand your place in my world curl into a furry donut i see a bird i stare at it i meow at it i do a wiggle come here birdy.'},
    {id: '2', title: 'Slices...', content:'Rub butt on table stare out the window yet meow. I like frogs and 0 gravity catasstrophe yet chase ball of string friends are not food lick the other cats all of a sudden cat goes crazy, or plan steps for world domination. '}
]

const postsSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'posts',
    initialState,
    reducers:{
        ADD_POST: {
            reducer: (state,action) => {
                state.push(action.payload)
            },
            //prepare callback is used so you don't have to repeat logic in multiple components.
            //can generate unique ids, format object, return a payload
            prepare: (title,content, userId) => {
                return {
                    payload: {
                        id:nanoid(),
                        title,
                        content,
                        userId
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
})

export const selectAllPosts = (state) => state.posts
//tracks changes in state shape

export const { ADD_POST } = postsSlice.actions

export default postsSlice.reducer
```

Currently, everything in the post is being rendered properly (title, content), but the author matching a given id is not being rendered. Any thoughts as to what is going wrong here?

Comment: could you gibe us the code for `selectAllPosts` et `postSlice` ?

Comment: Sweet have just added it

Comment: Maybe it's a mistake but I can't see any `userId` in your posts `initialState`? So `post.userId` is `undefined` and obviously the `find` fails